# Derivations of an algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modules, differential

I am reading how derivations of an algebra work. I am following the reference: Introduction to affine group schemes, Waterhouse. After having defined $\Omega_B=B^n$ for $B=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and having shown that $\Omega_B$ satisfies Der$_k$($B,M)\cong \hom_B(\Omega_B,M)$, we now want to define $\Omega_A$ for $A$ a generic $k$-algebra (which is the then of the form $A=B/I$).

The book defines it as $\Omega_A=\Omega_B/I \cdot \Omega_B+B \cdot dI$, where $d: B \rightarrow \Omega_B$ is the map $dX_i=e_i$, $e_i$ the generator of the $i$-th $B$ in the direct sum of $\Omega_B$. I am not sure that $\Omega_B/I$ is. Does it mean that $I$ acts trivially and so $\Omega_B/I$ acts on $\Omega_B$ by multiplication of the representative? Is it $\Omega_B/I=\Omega_{B/I}$?

Hope someone can clarify this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It probably means
$$
\Omega_A = \frac{\Omega_B}{I\cdot \Omega_B+B\cdot dI}
$$
So you're taking the quotient of $\Omega_B=B^n$ by the submodule generated by everything of the form $df$ for $f\in I$ and everything of the form $fdx_i$ for $f\in I$ (otherwise it wouldn't even be a $B/I$-module).

Comment: And $I$ acts on $\Omega_B$ as $f \cdot (g_1,...,g_n)=(fg_1,...,fg_n)$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.